# How to configure IIS7 so I can Upload from WebMatrix with Web Deploy?

Tags: iis-7, upload, webmatrix, webdeploy

How Would I configure IIS so I can upload a site from WebMatrix to a remote Windows server 2008 server? What would i put in on webmatrix in the boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install WebMatrix on your servers, what you need to install is Web Deploy v2:

> http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

There's a good article on how to install it here:

> http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2011/04/05/announcing-web-deploy-2-0-refresh.aspx

There's also a whole load of good stuff about Web Deploy here:

> http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deploy/

Comment: Webmatrix is on my computer at home. What I'm using to build the website. I just don't know how to configure both the web deploy on iis and WebMatrix.